# Flipping the sign of a number inside of a for loop based on whether the iterator is odd or even

Tags: python

I'm performing a calculation several times within a for loop, and want to change the sign of one of the pieces of the equation to positive or negative depending on if the iterator is odd or even. Simplified:

```
for i range(1, 5):
    return piece_1 + piece_2 + piece_3

# i = 1, piece_1 + piece_2 + (-piece_3)
# i = 2, piece_1 + piece_2 + piece_3
# i = 3, piece_1 + piece_2 + (-piece_3)
# i = 4, piece_1 + piece_2 + piece_3
```

I wrote the following function and am multiplying it by `piece_3` to get my desired output:

```
def neg_if_odd(i):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1

for i range(1, 5):
    return piece_1 + piece_2 + (neg_if_odd(i) * piece_3)
```

Is there a better, more ~elegant~ way of doing this, without the `neg_if_odd()` function?

Comment: Why don't you pass both the index and piece_3 to the function and directly return -piece_3 or piece_3 when appropriate?

Comment: I think using `yield` is better...

Comment: But this always returns on the first loop.

Comment: I think this is a better question for the Code Review site since it doesn’t seem like a specific programming question a lot of people are likely to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i range(1, 5):
    return piece_1 + piece_2 + (-1)**i * piece_3
```

or

```
for i range(1, 5):
    piece_3 *= -1
    return piece_1 + piece_2 + piece_3
```

Comment: piece3 should be piece_3

Comment: No, at every iteration it changes its own sign

Comment: oh right!! i missed that

Comment: The first one would work except the way you have it it will always negate odds (-1^1 and -1^3 are -1) you should make the exponent (i+1) -> (-1)**(i+1)

Comment: He wants -1 for odd i, so (-1)**i is right

Comment: (-1)**i is exactly what I was looking for. I knew there was something this simple I just couldn't claw it out of my rusty memory. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Could do something along the lines of:

```
for i in range(1,5):
    yield piece_1 + piece_2 + ( -1**i * piece_3 )
```

All this is doing is multiplying `piece_3` by -1<sup>i</sup>, which is -1 if when i is odd, and 1 if it's even.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be:

```py
for i in range(1, 5):
    return piece_1 + piece_2 + piece_3 * (-1 if i % 2 == 0 else 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def setter(piece_1, piece_2, piece_3):
    for i in range(1, 5):
        piece_3 *= -1
        yield piece_1 + piece_2 + piece_3

list(setter(1, 2, 3))
```

or:

```
piece_1, piece_2, piece_3 = 8, 6, 4
[piece_1 + piece_2 + piece_3 * (-1)**(i + 1) for i in range(1, 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**`itertools.cycle`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) which repeats a sequence over and over again:

```
from itertools import cycle

for piece_3 in cycle((-piece_3, piece_3)):
    yield piece_1 + piece_2 + piece_3
```

Comment: I think your loop is infinite...

Comment: @MoRe it appears that they created a generator function, which gets the next value whenever the `.next()` method is called. See [Generators in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generators-in-python/).

Comment: @blackbrandt but he must mention it for OP who probably don't know about generators

Comment: @MoRe I don't have to do anything. OP's question doesn't even have a proper loop, it returns on the first element.